# Spring elasticsearch how to generate mapping for all the fields?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Person class:

```
@Document(indexName = "person")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Person extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

  @Field(type=FieldType.Keyword)
  private String firstName;

  @Field(type=FieldType.Keyword)
  private String lastName;

  @MultiField(
      mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword),
      otherFields = {
          @InnerField(type = FieldType.Text, suffix = "ngrams", analyzer = "ik_max_word", searchAnalyzer = "ik_smart")
      })
  private String fullName;

  @Field
  private String maidenName;
}
```

I have an existing code that creates an index during startup:

```
 final IndexOperations indexOperations = this.elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(clazz);
      indexOperations.putMapping();
```

Now, I have a requirement to generate mappings from it and create mappings once. Can somebody help how can I integrate it with the existing code to include mappings of the fields to make them static?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the index needs to be created, if so, create it and write the mapping:

```java
indexOperations = operations.indexOps(entityClass);

if (!indexOperations.exists()) {
    indexOperations.createWithMapping();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean, use createWithMapping() instead of putMapping()?

What's the difference between the two methods?

Comment: `putMappings()`  needs the index to exists. Since you only can write the mapping once this is best done on index creation, that's the reason that we have the method that does index creation and writing the mapping in one single step.